# No sound with HDA Intel PCH

Tags: 12.10, sound, alsa

I don't manage to get sound working on my Ubuntu 12.10. The output of my alsa-info.sh is located [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=4e7e9ba1d3405de22a8f1a59e935e9a05459b4b4).

I would appreciate any help to fix this problem!

Comment: Possibly related http://askubuntu.com/q/800134/25388

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I've just resolved a no-sound problem on my HDA Intel PCH card: I ran 'alsamixer' in a terminal and unmuted the 'Line' column (with the M key).

Other info:

- I also made sure to unmute the Master, Headphone, Front, Surround, Center and LFE columns, but it's only when I unmuted Line that sound got out.
- The 'Chip' line in alsamixer says 'Realtek ALC887-VD'.
- The sound software never complained about the sound device.
- My system is Ubuntu 12.04.
  The speakers are connected to the green connector at the back of the PC.
- I tested the speakers with another computer.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on my Asus K55A laptop, and I fixed it by doing the following:

open terminal and:

**sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf**

at the end of the script add this line:

**options snd-hda-intel model=pch position_fix=1**

**ctrl+x** to exit

When you try to exit it will ask yout to save, enter "**Y**" then "**Enter**"

It will then ask you what file name you want to save it as, Do Not Change It!! Just hit "**Enter**"

Restart your machine and you should be good to go!!

Comment: I think you mean :wq to exit in vi. Ctrl-x is going to decrement the number under the cursor in vi.  Ctrl-x is for exiting nano. Since this is an Ubuntu site I've gone ahead and edited your post so it uses nano.