# ubuntu mate no sound intel hda

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, asus, eeepc, hda-intel

I've purchased an older netbook from asus: EeePC x101CH with an intel HDA sound chip. I installed ubuntu mate 15.04 and tried already several things to get te sound working, but to no avail. I already checked if it was mutes in the alsamixer, re-installed pulseaudio and also edited the alsa-base.conf as described here:

[12.10 no sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278503/no-sound-with-hda-intel-pch)
Maybe I did something wrong? Can anyone help me to get the sound chip working please?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out myself using this [fix](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/fix-hda-intel-realtek-alc887-no-sound.html): turned out i needed the 'generic' parameter instead